# Will I ever get a Facebook Looking back video again?

Tags: facebook

I got a facebook looking back movie, however, I didn't post it immediatly. I then deleted some photos and went back to watch the rest of the video then share it, but all I saw were like six pictures.I wish to know if I will ever get a video again.

Answer (score -1):

We learned a few hours ago that "Facebook is working on an edit tool" via [this TechCrunch article](http://techcrunch.com/2014/02/05/dont-like-your-facebook-look-back-youll-be-able-to-edit-it-soon/) by Greg Kumparak. I don't think it gives an expected date for when this feature will be available, but it does say "soon".

Until then, you can view your lookback video here (while logged in) as many times as you want to.

> http://www.facebook.com/lookback

Also, I believe you're missing the point to a "lookback" if you're just going back and deleting items in history. To each their own, though. :)

Comment: The video does not appear to be available any more. All that's there is your profile and background image and a generic "thank you" from Mark Zuckerberg.

Answer (score -2):

You can get that as many times you want..
using this below link

https://facebook.com/lookback/

Comment: The video does not appear to be available any more. All that's there is your profile and background image and a generic "thank you" from Mark Zuckerberg.